# PHP 5.4 connection to MS SQL server 2008 r2

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Am want to connect to an existing MS-SQL database on local host i have installed MS-SQL drivers 3.0 and edited php.ini to enable the extension i.e.

```
 extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

i have installed native client 10.0 and get this error:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string 'IMSSP' (length=5)
      'SQLSTATE' => string 'IMSSP' (length=5)
      1 => int -49
      'code' => int -49
      2 => string 'This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712' (length=216)
      'message' => string 'This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client. Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712' (length=216)
```

If i try to install Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client the error is operating system not supported.

The server is running MS Server 2008 R2, MS-SQL 2008 R2 and Apache 2.4.4

Comment: Did you get the right version? Can't install a 64bit native client on a 32bit os, or vice versa

Comment: The server is 64 bit, the native client installer installs both 64 and 32 bit or so i seem to understand here

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it seems you need to download and install "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for x86" which should be available from here:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1458276-2799-1.aspx

Make sure you get the right version of Native Client for your operating system

that page has all links on getting MSQL working for you.

Comment: OK tried everything on the page but still not working, got an idea how why native client 2012 will not install? I am running update on the server now which should fix windows installer compatibility issue